# i need to find "status": "failed" in the json file in jupyter notebook but it is showing syntax error i was using same jq command in javascript

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jq

i'm new to python i need to use jq on an Json file and find match for "status" : "failed" in file, i had tried this in js code using this

```
jq -r '.' *.json | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c '"status": "failed"'
```

it worked now i need to use it in jupyter notebook using below command it is not working giving syntax error,

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

cmd=['cd', 'Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports', '&&'','jq -r '.' *.json' | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c "status": "failed"']
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
print(result)
```

any help would be much appreciated, thanks i'm new to python

it says below error [image]

Comment: if you use `shell=True` then you should use single string instead of list.

Comment: if you want only display it then you can use directly `jq` in separated cell in  jupyter notebook, or with prefix `!` (or maybe `%`) in any other cell.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have too much `'` after `&&` ad this gives syntax error. But there are other mistakes in command

Comment: You cannot use quotes embedded in other quotes without escaping them. This is a typo at best. »**Not reproducible or was caused by a typo** While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.«

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `shell=True` then you have to use single string instead of list

```
cmd = "cd Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports && jq -r '.' *.json | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c '\"status\": \"failed\"'"
```

And rest is the same:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In original list you have two `''` after `&&` and this makes first problem.
There are also other problems with `'` in other parts.
But if you use `|` then you have to use `shell` and you don't need  list.

But if you would have to use list then there is standard module `shlex` to convert string to list

```
import shlex

cmd = "cd Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports && jq -r '.' *.json | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c '\"status\": \"failed\"'"

print(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Result:

```
['cd', 'Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports', '&&', 'jq', '-r', '.', '*.json', '|', 'jq', '(.steps) |= []', '|', 'grep', '-c', '"status": "failed"']
```

(but `|` will not work without `shell=True`)

Comment: Hi @furas thanks for the response i had tried your solution but not it has started showing FileNotFoundError
Input In [18], in <cell line: 7>()
      5 cmd = "cd /Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports/ && jq -r '.' *.json | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c '\"status\": \"failed\"'"
if you can guide here thanks

Comment: did you use it with `shell=True` and as string without `[ ]` ? if you use it without `shell=True` then it will treats it as one long filename, not shell commands. You have to change only `cmd` to single string and still use `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)`

Comment: okay got it @furas,  thank you so much you saved my day, one thing i want to check when the condition is failing for some file it says 
CalledProcessError: Command 'cd /Users/avinash/Downloads/reports/reports/ && jq -r '.' *.json | jq '(.steps) |= []' | grep -c '"status": "failed"'' returned non-zero exit status 1. how can i handle exit status 1, thanks

Comment: you can put code in `try/except` to catch it.